# How use Phantom deeplink in js?

Tags: phantom, phantom-wallet, deeplink

I have a dapp that users enter with a mobile browser, the website is with js, and I didn't see any examples of how to deeplink with js, only react was an example.
I used the link below, but it does not open Phantom

```
<a href="https://phantom.app/ul/v1/connect" >phantom</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from react you can use whatever js method you prefer to construct and render the deeplink on your site. Use the format detailed [here](https://docs.phantom.app/phantom-deeplinks/deeplinks-ios-and-android) to construct your link.